# how do i change an elivated batch files directory to the location of the batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, directory, location

Can anyone tell me how to change an elevated batch files directory to the location of the batch file? I am trying to make a program and it won’t work unless it is elevated and it has files it needs in the save folder. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are referring to is when you 'Run as Administrator' the current directory changes and you can't reference folders/files unless you use the full path.  To set the curent directory to the directory of the batch file add this line near the beginning of your bat file (before your reference any folders/files).

```
pushd "%~dp0"
```